# How to render a macro with a shortcode in Timber?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I would like to create a shortcode that calls on a timber/twig macro. I do not have it working, and I'm wondering if the trick is I'm not loading the macros anywhere. So I tried to 'compile' it in... or render it, but that's not working either. Is there a good way to do this?

**Base Template**

```
{% import "macros/widgets.twig" as widgets %}
```

**Content**

```
[notice title="My notice"]Some content in here[/notice]
```

**Shortcode**

```
add_shortcode('notice', 'notice_shortcode');
function notice_shortcode( $atts, $content = "" ){
    $title = sanitize_text_field($atts['title']);
    $string = "{{ widgets.notice({ title: '$title', content: '$content' }) }}";
    Timber::compile('macros/widgets.twig'); //??????
    return Timber::compile_string($string);
}
```

**Macro**

```
//macros/widgets.twig

{% macro notice(options) %}
    <div class="notice-block content-area">
        <h2><span class="icon icon-alert notice-block-icon"></span> {{ options.title }}</h2>
        {{ options.content }} 
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: You'll need to add an `{% import "macros/widgets.twig" as widgets %}` somewhere, before you can use the macro. You could place it before `{{ widgets.not....`, as `twig` would just re-import the macro when calling twice, but if you are using a `base` template of which you extend you can place it at the top of that `base` template file

Comment: Hey.. should have mentioned I am importing the Macro in my base template. looks like it's not getting over to the shortcode though

Comment: Seems it runs in another scope then. But perhaps that `$string = "{% import "macros/widgets.twig" as widgets %}{{ widgets.notice({ title: '$title', content: '$content' }) }}";` will work then, although it seems like overkill for this

Comment: that worked! makes sense. It does seem ... wrong ... though doesn't it? I think it would be kinda nice to have macros *and* shortcodes for a number of UI components

Comment: Yeah the method seems off to me as well. Surely there is a better aproach for doing this